# Pan to an Open InfoWindow Without Using InfoWindow.open()

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if it's possible to manually pan to an InfoWindow using the same behavior as `InfoWindow.open()` without actually calling `InfoWindow.open()`. The reason I wish to do this is to ensure that the InfoWindow is entirely on screen (just in case the user pans the map) while avoiding the "flicker" caused by re-opening an already open InfoWindow

I have tried using `Map.panTo()` to pan to the InfoWindow's marker position, but this centers the map on the marker, rather than doing the minimal amount of work to pan the InfoWindow into view as `InfoWindow.open()` does.

I also contemplated using `Map.panToBounds()` to imitate the auto-pan behavior of `InfoWindow.open()`, but I thought I would ask here before continuing down that path.

Comment: You could always `setCenter` the map to the infowindow's `getPosition`...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, but couldn’t find anything to trigger the “pan-to-infowindow” behaviour manually.
But since I found a re-opening not to “flicker” at all – at least in v3 of the API – I’m simply closing the infowindow, updating its contents and re-opening it again, to get the desired behaviour (just as you suggested):

```
infowindow.close()
infowindow.setContent("New Content")
infowindow.open(map, marker)
```